# How to select list-order value using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi guys im trying to make my page slide left or right depending on which menu item you click. Each menu item Has a list order value. Ideally it should be like this:

If li is clicked whose list order data is greater than the current selected list order content slide left. This is what i have so far

```
if ($("#menu_step_").data("listorder") <= ($("#menu_step_").data("listorder"))) { alert("left") }
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#menu_step_").data("listorder")` is a string. If you want to do a numeric comparison you need to make this into a number:

```
parseInt($("#menu_step_").data("listorder")) <= parseInt(($("#menu_step_").data("listorder"))
```

Comment: k i changed it to this  if (parseInt($("#menu_step_ .selected").data("listorder") < (parseInt($("#menu_step_").data("listorder"))))) { alert("left") } but nothing happens

Comment: See my edits. Your brackets are all in the wrong place.

Comment: when i use your code nothing happens, the alert does not display, if i write it like if ($("#menu_step_ .selected").on("click", "MenuSelect('menubar')") < ('li[id*="#menu_step"]')) { alert("left") } then i get the alert